# Regex: How can I capitalize the first letter that immediately follows a number EXCEPT for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc

Tags: regex, regex-negation

So basically I'm editing my regex code for a mass mp3 rename tool and was hoping there's a code to capitalize every letter that follows a number. For instance, **2nite** > **2Nite** and **221b** > **221B** but keep **11th** > **11th** and **2nd > 2nd** unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what language you're using. Here's what you'd do in perl

```
s/(?<=\d)(?!(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b)([[:lower:]])/\u$1/g
```

where

- `(?<=\d)` look behind for a digit
- `(?!(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b)` look ahead for not "st" or "nd" or ...

  - `\b` is a word boundary marker, so `1st` stays intact but `1stop` becomes `1Stop`
- `([[:lower:]])` a lower case letter (captured)
- `\u$1` in the replacement side, upper case the first letter of the text in the first capturing parentheses

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using any language. This is for mp3tag which uses foobar2000 script, if that helps. Edit: How can I use this to FIND and then REPLACE?

Comment: It's important to know what "flavour" of regular expressions your tool uses. There are basic, extended, perl-compatible. There is no "standard" regex.

Comment: I only have to write the regex code. The slash characters before and after are unnecessary and it is pretty detailed where I can $1$lower($2) so I'd assume extended.